# Why are my strings not being printed correctly?

Tags: c++, string, printing, output, cout

I want to write a piece of code to create a list of random potions for D&D 5e from a few given parameter lists. And I was almost done, every bit of code working properly apart from a single line of code.

I expect an output of this sort: "The liquid is: Yellow with flecks of colour.".
Instead, I get this: " with flecks of colour.". Basically, the entire part with:
"The liquid is: " gets omitted. Weirdly enough it works fine in one single case, when the colour is "Dark Red".

Here is the minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> appearance;
    std::vector<std::string> appearance_2;
   
    std::ifstream d_appearance("appearance.txt");//20 entries
    std::ifstream d_appearance_2("appearance_2.txt");//20 entries

    std::string line;
    std::string line_2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        getline(d_appearance, line);
        appearance.push_back(line);

        getline(d_appearance_2, line_2);
        appearance_2.push_back(line_2);
    }

    std::random_device generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> twenty_dis(0,19);

    std::string p_appearance = appearance[twenty_dis(generator)];
    std::string p_appearance_2 = appearance_2[twenty_dis(generator)];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        std::ostringstream s_look;
        s_look << "The liquid is; " << p_appearance << " with " << p_appearance_2;
        std::string look = s_look.str();
        std::cout << look << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it's ok if I just put the text files here as code blocks:
Appearance

```
Clear
Blue
Green
Red
Pale Green
Pink
Light Blue
White
Black
Dark Grey
Light grey
Yellow
Orange
Gold
Orange
Bronze
Metallic
Purple
Brown
Dark Red
```

Appearance_2

```
flecks of colour.
swirls of colour.
fizzing bubbles.
bubbles suspended in it.
some kind of bone floating in it.
leaves and flowers in it.
two separated liquid phases.
a bright glow.
a soft glow.
stripes of colour.
translucency.
a cloudy murkiness.
blood within it.
dirt floating in it.
chunks of metal in it.
some type of gore from a slain creature.
steam coming from it.
a face in the liquid.
constantly moving and shifting liquid.
a constant heat.
```

Comment: How many values do you think you can store in a single string? Consider using a vector of std::string.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: @JimRogers I am not sure what you mean but the issue is still present when I use four std::cout commands and try to print each part of the message manually. Instead of printing them with a single command as one long string.

Comment: i run the same code in vs and it just work fine with every single try as you wish. I can't see a problem.

Comment: @Leon-JosipDzojic Did you make sure those files were opened successfully?  Apparently you just assumed that the files were opened successfully, when possibly they were not.  When I use `cin` and changed the loop, I cannot [duplicate the issue](https://ideone.com/udtlh4).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, I haven't. Any advice on how to do that in this case?

Comment: @Leon-JosipDzojic `if ( !d_appearance || !d_appearance_2) { then one of the files did not open successfully }`.  And then if that happens, don't execute the code that assumes both files are valid.  Probably you want to simply print an error and `return -1;` or something like that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you very much. I just did it but it seems they both open just fine.

Comment: I would recommend not using a `std::random_device` to feed your distributions. Entropy is a limited resource. Use it to seed a PRNG like `std::mt19937`. Then feed the PRNG to your distributions.

Comment: What are the line endings in your files? What OS are you running this program in?

Comment: @sweenish Thank you. And how does one do that, I am sorry I am struggling a bit.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov That's a great catch! I forgot to think about it. I created the files on windows 10 then used a cloud service to move them to unix based system. (Ubuntu)

However, the line ending do see to be the linux ones (Ln).

Comment: @Leon-JosipDzojic -- Well, the joke that I've been told about the error you encountered is that "you can't tell a lie to the runtime about the type of file you are dealing with".  Don't worry, there are a *lot* of programs out there that do not work correctly when given Windows text files when running under Unix/Mac, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be the problem with line endings. If you created the file in Windows (thus you have `"\r\n"` line endings) and use this file in Linux, the `getline` would work differently. It will use `'\n'` as a delimiter, but will treat `'\r'` as a separate string. As the result you may get some appearences equal to `"\r"`. At the end of the day you could output that:

```cpp
std::ostringstream s_look;
s_look << "The liquid is; " << "\r" << " with " << p_appearance_2;
std::string look = s_look.str();
std::cout << look << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

That will override the beginning of the string, so you don't see the `"The liquid is; "` in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, your code snippet doesn't change anything in my case. I also tried changing the end of line sequence to CRLF in VS Code. But it also didn't help.
Do you think it could perhaps help if I made new txt files on the Linux system?

Comment: I created new txt files on the linux system and that solved the issue. Thank you very much for the help.